Bootstrap 4 Problemas con alinear checkbox input
He creado un modal usando el sistema de grid especificado por Bootstrap 4 pero tengo problemas para agregar un checkbox al inicio de la primera fila haciendo que se vea desealineado con las demas columnas y filas.

¿De casualidad sabran como se puede alinear el checkbox apropiadamente?.
He intentado usar propieades css como align-items o align-content pero no con much exito, quizas ustede sepan como definir el checkbox apropiadamente o una alternativa a ello.
Les comparto mi modal:
<div id="modalS"class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        
      <div class="modal-content">            
        
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">FORMULARIO</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <form id="formularioS">
                <div id="au">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                      <label class="col-form-label-lg" style="font-weight: bold;">Antecedentes:</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row mb-2">
                  <div class="form-check col-sm-1 col-lg-2">
                    <br>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="9999" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Cargo Vacante</label>
                  </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                      <label for="rut">Cedula de indentidad</label>
                      <input id="rut" name="rut" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="11111111-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                      <label for="an">Apellidos Nombres</label>
                      <input id="an" name="an" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled readonly style="font-weight: bold;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                      <label for="corr">C</label>
                      <select id="corr" name="corr" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
                        <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                      <label for="rut2">Cedula de indentidad</label>
                      <input id="rut2" name="rut2" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="11111111-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                      <label for="an2">Apellidos Nombres</label>
                      <input id="an2" name="an2" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled readonly style="font-weight: bold;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                      <label for="corr2">C</label>
                      <select id="corr2" name="corr2" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
                        <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>

                
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btnCancelar" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="guardarFormularioSolicitud()">Guardar</button>
        </div>
        

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


Amigo, nunca entiendo como corregir estos problemas, me quedaré a ver la solución si alguien la agrega. Llevo intentando todo lo que se, y nada, sigue quedando uno arriba del otro xD

Creo que la versión 5 no tiene este problema, en cualquier caso creo al día de hoy no tiene mucho sentido utilizar el sistema de grillas de boostrap, css nativo tiene mejores y más limpias soluciones.  Puedes agregar un label en blanco arriba y luego otro form-group

<div class="form-group col-sm-1 col-lg-2"><label for="flexCheckDefault">&nbsp;</label><div class="form-group col-sm-12"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="9999" id="flexCheckDefault"><label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Cargo Vacante</label></div></div>  No sé si será la mejor solución (por eso no te respondo formalmente). Por otro lado te aviso que tu HTML está mal formado, tienes algunos div de sobra

Lo único que se me ocurre son 3 cosas: 1. remover el <br>, 2. agregar la clase align-items-center en la fila correspondiente a ese checkbox y esos input, 3. agregar la clase mt-4 al mismo <div> que contiene la clase form-check. No es perfecto, pero es lo que más se acerca. Para el punto 3., en todo caso, podrías crear una clase extra donde el margin-top sea de 2 rem (ya que mt-4 da un margin-top de 1.5 rem). Eso haría que se vea aún más centrado con respecto al campo de texto más cercano.

A mi me parece que lo mejor sería reemplazar el checkbox por un select con 3 opciones: Indicar, Si y No. De esta forma por un lado podes asegurarte de que el usuario sepa que tiene que indicar una opción y por otro lado, forzarlo a indicar o por si o por no.

Ojala fuera esa una opcion, pero no. Aun asi, gracias por ese comentario.

Encontre una forma algo aceptable, agregando un align-items-center al div que contiene todos los items de la fila y un text-align: right al div del checkbox.


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="modalS" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">FORMULARIO</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <form id="formularioS">
            <div id="au">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                  <label class="col-form-label-lg" style="font-weight: bold;">Antecedentes:</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row mb-2" style="align-items: center;">
                <div class="form-check col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style=" text-align: right; ">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="9999" id="flexCheckDefault">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Cargo Vacante</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                  <label for="rut">Cedula de indentidad</label>
                  <input id="rut" name="rut" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="11111111-1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                  <label for="an">Apellidos Nombres</label>
                  <input id="an" name="an" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled readonly style="font-weight: bold;">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                  <label for="corr">C</label>
                  <select id="corr" name="corr" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
                    <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-2">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                <label for="rut2">Cedula de indentidad</label>
                <input id="rut2" name="rut2" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="11111111-1">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                <label for="an2">Apellidos Nombres</label>
                <input id="an2" name="an2" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled readonly style="font-weight: bold;">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                <label for="corr2">C</label>
                <select id="corr2" name="corr2" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled>
                  <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btnCancelar" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="guardarFormularioSolicitud()">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalS">
  Launch demo modal
</button>



Encontre otra alternativa:
Anidar el div que tiene el checkbox en otro div con clase col, por lo que ví alinea alinea su inicio con los demas divs:
...
<div class="row mb-2" style="align-items: center;">
<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                    <br>
                  <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="9999" id="ausentado_vacante">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="ausentado_vacante">Cargo Vacante</label>
                  </div></div>
...


Por cierto: es identidad, no indentidad.
